# solution of $y^2 - x = 15$ and $x^2 -xy = 2009$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

Find all the integer solutions to the equations:

\begin{eqnarray}
y^2 - x &=& 15  \\ 
x^2 -xy &=& 2009
\end{eqnarray}

Not sure how to solve this :/, tried the usual algebra way (solving for something and substetuting) but didn't really work out

$x+15$ must be a square number, so $x$ has to be $1,10,21,34,49,\ldots$

Using $49$ it works and gives me a solution, but is that the only one? And if, how do I show it.

Comment: What do you mean by the symbol "|".

Comment: $x$ divides $2009=7^2\cdot 41$.

Comment: @lhf I think the vertical line is just separating the two equations in this case.

Comment: Someone with more reputation should tag as diophantine-equation or something.

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+{y^2-x%3D15%2Cx^2-xy%3D2009}) shows two real solutions and two complex solutions, with only the one you found in the integers.  You wind up with a quartic

Comment: thanks, lhf :)
I shall remind myself to always do the prime factorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x² -xy = 2009

x(x-y)=1*2009 =2009 *1 =-2009 *(-1)=(-1)*(-2009)

x(x-y)=7*287 =... like that

x(x-y)=49*41=...like above

find x,y then compare with other equation